# Launch video player in iOS from a link rather than an embedded video

Tags: ios, video, vimeo

Sorry if this has been asked before... in a mobile browser (eg iOS Safari) when a Vimeo video is embedded into a HTML page, clicking play on the video pops it open in the native player in Safari - I want to be able to launch a video in this exact way, but from an image link rather than having to embed the video... So that clicking the image pops open the video in the native Safari player.

I've searched around but think I'm lacking the correct terminology to know exactly what to search for.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to embed the vimeo code?

One work around can be going to your vimeo video settings, then Basic and at the bottom of that page upload your own Thumbnail image... You will still have to embed the vimeo code though, but now you will have the image you want as the first image before you click on the video.

- This can be a partial solution in the mean time. Also I think a Pro vimeo account might allow a direct link to a video.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply... The reason I don't want to embed is that we have an image slider on the mobile site in lieu of a background video (desktop site has a background video), so we want the user to have the option to either watch the slider, or press to watch the video... so my query is more about how I get that press to trigger the native video player in eg. Safari or Chrome.

Otherwise the custom thumbnail is a good fallback option... thanks for suggesting.

Comment: The only way to have a direct link to the video so you can link to an image (to do what you want to do) is by having a Vimeo Pro account. [https://vimeo.com/help/faq/managing-your-videos/video-settings#how-do-i-use-a-third-party-player-with-vimeo-pro]

Comment: Ok cheers, I'll have a play and post results here... thanks for the replies.